# Highlight Annotation is not highlighting the line i want

Tags: 18.04

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS and I'm trying to use the document viewer and when I try to use the highlight annotation it highlights the line below and to the left of what I would like to know if there is  a way to fix this or a method to be more precise with what I want to highlight

Comment: Hello Richard. It is a little bit hard to say what you are viewing without a screenshot or maybe a video on YouTube. Can you please provide a screenshot at least? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine if you would be working with a PDF file that displays the actual text as characters, and not as a graphic scanned from a paper document.

My guess is that your current file is a PDF obtained by scanning a document. What you see is a "photo" of the document. In addition, your PDF contains actual text (i.e., characters), obtained from optical character recognition. That makes the PDF searchable while retaining the look of the originally scanned document. The location of the (hidden) text may not agree well with the text displayed on the image of the document.

The document viewer is not to blame. You will have the issue with this file in any PDF viewer. You will not have the issue with a document that is, for example, created from within a word processor.